# C++ Embarcadero TTcpServer and TTcpClient

Tags: c++, c++builder

I want to know how to work with connected clients on TTcpServer class?
I got a client connected on method "ServerAccept" whats next? How can i work with them?
I need to start from ServerAccept a new thread to work with socket client?

Comment: These two TT's look almost like a Cyrillic "П". Retarded naming convention...

Comment: Nothing. Just read a documentation, it has an example of usage in it - http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Sockets_TTcpServer.html

Comment: I did everything like in this example but still dunno how.

Comment: That is sad... Perhaps you should read more generic stuff first? Check out the book called UNIX network programming by Stevens.

Comment: I dont fully understand the object TTcpServer not the network basis. i see you dont know it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TTcpServer.OnAccept` event is triggered when the `TTcpServer.Accept()` method is called and a client is accepted.  **ALL** socket work with that client has to be done within the context of the `TTcpServer.OnAccept` event, using the methods of the `TCustomIpClient` object that is provided by the event.  As soon as the event handler exits, `TTcpServer` closes the connection.  If the `TTcpServer.BlockMode` property is set to `bmThreadBlocking`, the `OnAccept` event handler runs in a thread managed by `TTcpServer` so you do not need to create your own thread.  Otherwise, you need to call the `TTcpServer.Accept()` method in your own code, in which case you can call it in your own thread if desired.